# Is there an authoritative definition of what a terrorist is?

Tags: definition

An intelligent unbiased observer from another galaxy wants to understand the notion of a 'terrorist' because the alien sees:

“One man’s terrorist is another man’s freedom fighter”

Is there an authoritative definition of terrorism that would enable a set of unbiased observers arrive at consistent labeling of terrorism and freedom fighters?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with concepts of "unbiased observers" and definitions of politically charged terms terms and is better asked at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ or https://politics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What makes you think an alien would be an unbiased observer?  They would judge based on their own culture, which may consider democracy to be unethical etc.

Comment: @Moo  There is no reason to believe that a given alien is or is not biased.  However, the bespoke *hypothetical* alien is unbiased for this discussion and is a given to facilitate the discussion

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definition_of_terrorism

Comment: The quote in the question is not a universal law, nor is it an axiom. It's just a quote. The two terms are not mutually exclusive. A freedom fighter might be a terrorist if he deliberately targets civilians in a showy way, or might not be if he only attacks legitimate military targets. Even the USA, which is often accused of labeling its enemies as "terrorists", uses the terms "militant" or "insurgent" for those who attack US military bases.

Comment: @vsz's comment is on point: the categories "freedom fighter" and "terrorist" are not necessarily mutually exclusive, even considering only one person's subjective definitions of those terms.

Comment: If the problem was visualized with a Venn diagram, then the goal is to seek the minimum union between the two labels, ideally to the point where they were mutually exclusive, but not necessarily

Comment: @gatorback : The goal? Why? And whose goal? One term means for what goals they are fighting, and the other means what methods they use. These could even be two axes on a grid plot.

Answer (score 16):

### There is a definition

Or rather, there are as many definitions as there are jurisdictions who have passed laws about them.

In [australia](/questions/tagged/australia), a terrorist is a person who commits a [terrorist act](https://www.ag.gov.au/NationalSecurity/Counterterrorismlaw/Pages/AustraliasCounterTerrorismLaws.aspx).

> A terrorist act is an act, or a threat to act, that meets both these criteria:
>
> - it intends to coerce or influence the public or any government by intimidation to advance a political, religious or ideological cause.
> - it causes one or more of the following:
>
> ◦  death, serious harm or danger to a person
>
> ◦  serious damage to property
>
> ◦  a serious risk to the health of safety of the public
>
> ◦  serious interference with, disruption to, or destruction of critical infrastructure such as a telecommunications or electricity network.
>
> Advocating, protesting, dissenting or taking industrial action are not terrorist acts where the person doing the activity does not intend to cause serious harm to a person or create a serious risk to public safety.

If the Crown accuses someone of being a terrorist then they have to convince, beyond reasonable doubt, a set of unbiased observers (a jury) that they did these things.

“Freedom fighter” is not a term defined in Australian law so it would take on its normal meaning as someone who fights or otherwise struggles for “freedom” - a word that is so broad and subjective that it would be context dependent. Fighting could range from peaceful protest to armed insurrection. The hypothetical “freedom fighter” might or might not engage in “terrorist acts” so the terms “freedom fighter” and “terrorist” are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103277/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-terrorist-definition).

Answer (score 4):

The word "terrorist" (or "terrorism") is like any other word of the English language, which means that the notion of an "authoritative" definition is a bit sketchy. One finds definitions in dictionaries, and I suppose an authoritative definition is found in an authoritative dictionary. Your desideratum of an authoritative source precludes using Urbandictionary. Since there is no one *official* dictionary of English, you would have to go for one of the most respected dictionaries: The Oxford English Dictionary, or Merriam Webster's Third New International dictionary. It would in fact be best to provide both, since this could reveal differences in sources (and what they have in common).

Another approach would be to gather together statutory definitions. This is generally in inferior approach, because it does not correctly say how the word "terrorism" is defined, but if you were explaining to an alien lawyer how we statutorily define "terrorism", then of course you want to point to specific statutes. There are enough Anglophone countries that a comparative study could be interesting. It really depends on why you want to "define" terrorism/t.

At the US federal level, ["international terrorism"](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2331) is given a definition, applicable to Title 18. A seeming peculiarity is that the act must

> occur primarily outside the territorial jurisdiction of the United
>   States, or transcend national boundaries in terms of the means by
>   which they are accomplished, the persons they appear intended to
>   intimidate or coerce, or the locale in which their perpetrators
>   operate or seek asylum

The reason for this is that, unlike many countries, there are federal and state levels of law-making, and under the US Constitution they are supposed to have distinct subject matters (hence regular robbery is not a federal crime). The aliens would have to understand this feature of US law, in order to understand the otherwise "incorrect" clause in the Title 18 definition. There is a different definition of terrorism under [Title 22](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/22/2656f#d_1), pertaining to the obligation of the Sec'y of State to report on terrorism, which is

> premeditated, politically motivated violence perpetrated against
>   noncombatant targets by subnational groups or clandestine agents

and "international terrorism" is "terrorism involving citizens or the territory of more than 1 country". For purposes of the Attorney General, the [Code of Federal Regulations](https://ecfr.io/Title-28/pt28.1.0#se28.1.0_15) semi-defines terrorism by saying that

> Terrorism includes the unlawful use of force and violence against
>   persons or property to intimidate or coerce a government, the civilian
>   population, or any segment thereof, in furtherance of political or
>   social objectives

(Other things could be considered "terrorism", so this is an "at least" definition).

Comment: @use6726 The reason to define terrorism is to enable the unbiased observer / student to craft a 'bright-line' between terrorist and freedom fighter.  Ideally there would be a significant 'gulf' between then two.

Comment: @gatorback : No. The unbiased observer is needed to decide whether someone is a freedom fighter or not. To decide whether someone is a terrorist or not, is much less subjective. For example, a freedom fighter might also be a terrorist if he deliberately targets civilians in a showy way, or might not be if he only attacks legitimate military targets. It's not a line where "terrorist" is on one end, and "freedom fighter" on the other end.

Answer (score 2):

Even though we're on Law.SE, I would not look in law books for definitions of such terms. So,

> Is there an authoritative definition of terrorism that would enable a set of unbiased observers arrive at consistent labeling of terrorism and freedom fighters?

Well, with a caveat regarding the authoritativeness of dictionaries and the fluidity and context-sensitivity of language, I'd say "yes, but many people don't like it".

From [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/terrorism?s=t):

> **terrorism** [ ter-uh-riz-uh m ]
>
> 1. The use of violence and threats to intimidate or coerce, especially for political purposes.
> 2. the state of fear and submission produced by terrorism or terrorization.
> 3. a terroristic method of governing or of resisting a government.

Definitions (2.) and (3.) are derivatives of (1.), so (1.) is your basic definition.

From the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terrorism):

> **ter·​ror·​ism** | \ ˈter-ər-ˌi-zəm
>
> 1. the systematic use of terror especially as a means of coercion

and for "terror", we have (ommitting irrelevant definitions):

> **terror**, noun
>
> 1. a state of intense or overwhelming fear
> 2. violence or the threat of violence used as a weapon of intimidation or
>      coercion
> 3. a very frightening or terrifying aspect

The reason many people won't like it is that it's quite broad. As comments on other definitions indicate, it covers a lot of governmental activity, perhaps to the extent that most world states (including democracies) are ruled in part through terrorism.